# How to calculate rotation for geometries on a sphere so that they face outwards

Tags: math, three.js, rotation

I have a [sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HdUm.png) and I'm adding cylinders on the surface based on points (x, y, z) converted from coordinates(radius = 200). Now I'm stuck on how to individually calculate the needed rotation for each cylinders to face outwards from the sphere.

Im using Matrix4(makeRotationX(); and Matrix4(makeRotationZ(); to rotate the geometry.

```
function drawCylinder(x_values, y_values, z_values, scene) {

  var cylinderHeight = 20;
  var rotationX = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(Math.PI/2);
  var rotationZ = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(Math.PI/2);

  var axis = new THREE.Vector3(x_values, y_values, z_values);
  var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(2, 2, cylinderHeight, 32 );
  geometry.translate(x_values[0], y_values[0], z_values[0]);
  //geometry.applyMatrix4(rotationZ);

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x5affb5
  });
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  clearArrays();

}
```

Example(x: – 71.2237692444388, y: – 47.741840449353155, z: – 182.89858218456328)

Comment: You could simply use lookAt https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `quaternion.setFromUnitVectors()`, having a base vector and a vector of cylinder's position:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.setScalar(10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

let radius = 5;
let s = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(radius, 36, 18), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({wireframe: true}));
scene.add(s);

// cylinders
let g = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(0.125, 0.125, 1, 8);
g.translate(0, 0.5, 0);
let m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "orange"});
let baseV = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
let dirV = new THREE.Vector3();
for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
  let c = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
  c.position.setFromSphericalCoords(
    radius,
    Math.random() * Math.PI,
    Math.random() * Math.PI * 2
  );
  c.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(baseV, dirV.copy(c.position).normalize());
  scene.add(c);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(()=>{
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm after I understood what was everything meant :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not state the coordinates of the center of the sphere in your question. Let me call them `(x0, y0, z0)`.

The radius of the sphere is `R = 200` and the height of the cylinder is `cylinderHeight = 20`.

The bottom of the cylinder has coordinates `(x, y, z)`.

Since you want the cylinder to be oriented "vertically" on the Earth, you want the axis of the cylinder to be in the radial direction; in other words, you want the center of the sphere, the bottom of the cylinder and the top of the cylinder to be aligned. Another way to state this is that you want the two vectors Center->Bottom and Center->Top to be colinear. Yet another way to state this is that you want the coordinates of these two vectors to be proportional.

Since you know all the lengths involved, the proportionality factor has to be `(R + cylinderHeight) / R`.

Finally the coordinates `(xT, yT, zT)` of the top of the cylinder are given by:

```
(xT-x0, yT-y0, zT-z0) = (R + cylinderHeight) / R * (x-x0, y-y0, z-z0)

xT = (R + cylinderHeight) * (x-x0) / R + x0
yT = (R + cylinderHeight) * (y-y0) / R + y0
zT = (R + cylinderHeight) * (z-z0) / R + z0
```

Comment: This would have been a valid solution if you could control the location of bottom and the top of the object but to my knowledge you can only control the centre. Anyways clean solution and saved for possible future usage.